# "Failed to parse UUID" error message on attempting to login via TrueVault api

Tags: angularjs, truevault

On attempting to login via the truvault api using angular js, I am getting this error message: Failed to parse UUID. I am passing the username, password and account_id as params. I am successful using the curl command and get the success response.

The 400 error is not described in the api docs for authorization. I am not sure about if this UUID is linked to the schema_id. Would anyone (truevault guys!!) know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted truevault support on this one. Dan helped me get through it.

I was passing the username/password/account_id as url string query parameters. I had to make two changes to the code:
1. Pass the above as form data parameters
2. add the angular-post-fix.js to my project.
(Note: I am not adding the link as there are editors who will disallow the post with links to elsewhere. It has happened in the past!)

Answer (score 0):

When using Node.js, the `querystring` API is really useful. Just pass an object to the `querystring.stringify()` function, and the resulting output is ready to be sent to TrueVault for login.

Additionally, I found that adding the header `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8'` might be necessary (which is one of the things the Angular post-fix library does).

Answer (score 0):

@orthodoc is right, but is kind of tricky how to actually build the request. Lets say we are using [fetch](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/) with [formData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) params, I'd like to add an example of a successful request:

```
...
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('username', username);
formData.append('password', password);
formData.append('account_id', accountId);

return fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8'
  },
  body: formData
});
...
```